# Java's DataSource Equivalent in .net

Tags: java, .net, database, dao

Under .net (specifically C# really), is there an equivalent to Java's DataSource class?  I'm used to creating a single DataSource (pooled or non-pooled) and passing it around to objects that require creating new database connections.  Helpful in decoupled/dependency injection situations.

However under .net, instantiating a new SqlConnection seems to come from a pool [if you use the same connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).  Does that mean you should pass around a connection string (or connection string builder) to your DAO pattern classes, just pass around the single Connection object or create a new ConnectionProvider like class?

eg

```
class SomethingDao {
    DataSource dataSource;
    Something getSomething(int id) {
        connection = dataSource.GetConnection();
        connection.CreateCommand();
        ... etc
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enterprise Library takes care of virtually all of these details for you, so I recommend you consider using it and following the example code shown here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953187%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx

This link walks you through using it step-by-step.  The equivalent using Ent Lib would be the Database class.  It has all the code examples, so I won't repeat them here.

Comment: I never got a chance to use this in my previous position's codebase but I'll mark this as answered.